# Proof using false induce true

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am struggling with finding the difference between the next two "proofs"- one for correct statement and one for incorrect:

1. Transitivity of subset: If $ A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$ then A subset of C.
   Proof: Let $a \in A$ .then since A subset of B, a is in B, and since B subset of C, a is in C, as required. 
   Im wondering about the case where A is empty. On one hand, this proof doesn't cover it. Is it the case where we assumed false, and get that either the next claim is true or false, the "if ..than,," is true valued?

2.If $A-B=A $, then $ A \not\subset B$. The only case where it's not true is when A is empty..but very similar "proof" can be written. So how does false implies true/false isn't legal here?

Comment: An inclusion is a for all $x$ sentence and a true  for all $x$ sentence is really true for all  $x$ whatever . When, you assume that A is included in B, you assume that for all $x$ , $x$ is in A implies $x$ is in B . When A is empty, it is still true for all $x$ that $x$ is in A implies $x$ is in B. The fact that it is not true that $x$ is in A ( in case A is empty)  changes nothing to the fact that the for all $x$ *conditional* is still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1:

It is never assumed that $A$ is not empty. We are asked to prove $\forall a (a \in A \to a \in C)$. We did exactly that according to the rules of logic.

For question 2:

There is no proof at all of this statement, since it is not true. We cannot possibly have a similar proof, since we’re trying to show $\neg (\forall a (a \in A \to a \in B))$. We’re trying to prove the negation of a $\forall a$ statement, not a $\forall a$ statement itself.

If you still disagree, try to write out the “proof” for part 2, and I can point out which step is logically invalid.

Answer (score 1):

In the first *proof*, the case of the set $A$ being empty does not constitute any special circumstance.  The only way to disprove that $A \subset C$ is to establish that an element exists that is in $A$ and is not in $C$.  When $A$ is the empty set, establishing that $A$ contains such a special element is clearly impossible.

---

In the second proof, the premise that $A - B = A$ is equivalent to the premise that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  Note that if either $A$ or $B$ is the empty set, then it is impossible for $A$ and $B$ to share an element, so they are then automatically disjoint (i.e. non-intersecting sets).

In the second proof, the *conclusion* that $A$ is not a subset of $B$ is equivalent to the conclusion that there exists an element that is in $A$ but is not in $B$.  Given the premise of the second proof, as discussed in the previous paragraph, this conclusion will be true if and only if there exists an element that is in $A$.  That is, if there is such an element, then by the previous paragraph, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, such an element can not be in $B$, so $A$ can not be a subset of $B$.  Alternatively if $A$ is the empty set, then as discussed in the very first paragraph of this answer, $A$ is a subset to any other set.

---

I think that it is important for me to **emphasize** that my **entire answer** is based **only** on my intuition, rather than formal training in set theory.  As (merely) one example in this answer of where this may be relevant, it is unclear to me whether it is appropriate to declare sets $A$ and $B$ disjoint, if $A$ is the empty set.

I should also mention that I am interpreting the statement

$$A \subset B \tag1 $$

to represent merely that every element that is in $A$ is also in $B$.

That is, I am **not** interpreting the statement in (1) above to represent that $A$ is a *proper* subset of $B$, which would (also) denote that there is an element in $B$ that is not in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me take a guess at what proof you have in mind in 2:

Suppose $A - B = A$.  Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$.  Then since $A-B=A$, $x \in A - B$, so $x \notin B$.

This is a correct proof of the statement $\forall x(x \in A \to x \notin B)$.  However, that's not what $A \not\subset B$ means.  To prove $A \not\subset B$, you'd have to prove $\neg\forall x(x \in A \to x \in B)$.